# How to run Django server locally on master branch while I am developing on the other branch

Tags: django, git, git-branch

I'm setting up a Django 2.1 server and I want to run the server because it's servicing to my LAN. I want the server to keep running while I'm developing it on the other branch.

But the server downs when I change the branch; Actually its branch changes too!

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be developing and running production code from the same location. That's **really** bad practice. You can either:

1. Set up a second copy of your repo in another location that production code runs from (it will **only** ever be set to the master branch).
2. Develop your code on another system.

I always opt for number 2 above. I develop on my laptop (running everything locally), then deploy that to a Docker-ized Ubuntu system.